# Difference between conditional expectation and conditional probabilty

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

These are *known definitions*:
We have a probability space $(\Omega, A, P)$

Conditional probability is defined through $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}, P(B) > 0$. This is a **real nunmber**.

Then also where is conditional expectation $E[X|A_0]$ with $A_0$ being some subalgebra. This is a random variable. In the special case when $A_0$ is generated by a random variable $Y$ we also write $E[X|\sigma(Y)] = E[X|Y]$ and using the factorization theorem you can also write $E[X|Y]$ as a RV of $Y$ which you then denote as $E[X|Y=y]$. For $X$ being in indicator function we sometimes also write $E[1_A | Y=y] =: P(A | Y = y)$ which confuses me very much, because this now is the **evaluation of an only a.s. defined RV**

I am particular confused with the proof I state [in this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264848/sum-of-i-i-d-random-variables-is-a-markov-chain/).

Since the probability of $\{X_1 = i_1, ... X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}\}$ is 0 because the $X_i$ are real valued, the proof can't be talking about conditional probabilities. Thus I think the proof uses the sloppy notation for conditional expectation $E[1_B(X_n) | X_1 = i_1, ... X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}] =: P(X_n \in B | X_1 = i_1, ... X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})$. Now in this concept, I dont understand why the single steps in the proof are true. They are all obvious true for $P(|)$ being conditional probability, but in my eye not trivial for $P(|)$ being conditional expectations

Comment: "and because we can factorize the conditional expectation through Y, we now can write E[X|Y=y]" Huh? Your trouble here and in your previous question might be due to an unsufficient distinction between the random variable $E(X|Y)$ and the real valued function $y\mapsto E(X|Y=y)$. Please realize that the basic object here (and the only one always well defined) is the random variable $E(X|Y)$.

Comment: @Did, I clearified on that and also tried to make the question a bit more clear to what I need to know and what I don't understand

Comment: Am I just so much on the wrong track or does nobody know? I have a feeling I got the rest of the lecture by now, but this one proof doesn't get to me

Answer (score 1):

Let $X, Y$ be random variable, then the condition expectation is given by
$$
E(Y|X=x)=\int_{Y}yf_{Y|X=x}(x,y)dy=\int_{Y}y\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}dy=\int_{y\in Y}y\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\int_{t\in Y}f_{X,Y}(x,t)dt}dy
$$
where $x$ is any element in $X$. Therefore $E(Y|X=x)$ is function of $x$. Here the inner term $f_{Y|X}(x,y)$ is precisely coming from conditional distribution $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. One way to think about it is to consider the discrete case, then we have $P(Y=y|X=x)$ given by the quotient $\frac{P(Y=y, X=x)}{P(X=x)}$. And $P(X=x)=\sum_{y\in Y}P(X=x, Y=y)$.

For what you asked on the second part, I think it is important to note that for Markov chains, the probability transition function from one state to the next state is *independent* of the previous states. You can think about this as tossing a fat coin on the real line. Suppose the coin goes to position $x$ after $n$-steps, whether the coin goes to $x\pm 1$ in the next step would be totally independent of its past. In other words, given the coin has undergone $HTHTTT\cdots $sequence does not change the expectation we have given the $n$-th step it is at position $x$ at all. The coin does not remember that. To me this is what makes the Markov chain so nice and useful.

Comment: Conditional expectation exists more generally than just the discrete or continuous case. And what do you mean by $f_{Y\mid X}(x,y)$ is precisely coming from $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$?

Comment: It is rather disquieting to see (as in the first line of this post) computations of conditional expectations reduced to the only case when a joint PDF exists. No, *typical* random variables on R^2 do not have a PDF and no, this is not how to correctly define E(X|Y). That this is routinely done on the site makes one suspect that this only reflects the flawed approach to the subject these users were subjected to.

Comment: @Did: I totally agree. This sloppy approach is not what I really wanted, but being taught when I took the class myself.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that *if* $X$ *is an indicator of* $A$, then the expected value happens of $X$ is the probability of $Z \in A$ (and this is true regardless of whether one conditions on $Y$).  But that is not equivalent to saying that the definition of (conditional) expected value is equal to the definition of (conditional) probability.  You have simply demonstrated equality under a specific situation; in other words, you have applied the definitions to that situation.

Comment: How can the expected value of $X$ conditioned on $Y$ be the be the probability of $Z \in A$, if the first is an a.s. defined random variable and the second is a real number between 0 and 1?